# Как сделать список с бесконечной вложенностью в Android?

Tags: java, android

По клику на элемент списка нужно переходить на следующий список с элементами и так до бесконечности. Пробую через ExpandableListView, но дальше второго уровня пока не выходит. Может не в ту сторону копаю и надо что то другое?

Comment: https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView/blob/master/README.md?

Comment: хм, спасибо, надо попробовать